# Can i call a function using new in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to know that suppose i have a function say

```
int Add(int i, int j)
{
    return (i+j);
}
```

At any point can i call this function using new something like

```
int result = new Add(3,4);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem being solved.

Comment: What would you want to achieve by this code?

Comment: @MarounMaroun suppose i have something like this Derive():m_pObj(new Object()){} If i write this i won't compile in some of the old compiler that's why for backward compatibility we need to write it like Derive():m_pObj(new Object){}. Now why i ask the question is someone told me that if i call it with () it may lead to call a function. So is it true ??

Answer (score 3):

`new` returns  pointer to a dynamically allocated object. The syntax is of the form `new T(optional initializer expression)`. So you would need

```
int* result = new int(Add(3,4));
```